# The method placeWalls(char[][], int, Random) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (char, int, Random)

Tags: java

For the life of me and can't seem to figure out why it's saying char is a class in the Main and not in the method...

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random randGen = new Random();
    int r=0;
    int c=0;
    int number;
    int j = scnr.nextInt();
    char[][] room = new char [r][c];
    Main.placeWalls(room[20][10] ,10, randGen);
  }
  public static void placeWalls(char[][] room, int numberOfWalls, Random randGen) {

        for (int r = 0; r<room.length;r++){
            System.out.println(r);
               for (int c = 0; c < room[r].length;c++){
                  room[r][c] = '.';  // Initialize the cell
                  System.out.print(room[r][c]); // Display the content of cell board
               }
               System.out.println(' ');
               int a;
               for (a = 0; a < room.length; a++) {
                   int number = randGen.nextInt(room.length);
                   System.out.println(number);
               }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. What's the purpose of `r`, `c` and `room` inside `main()`? What's your intent in passing `room[20][10]` into `placeWalls()`?

Comment: The goal is to generate an array thats 20 by 10 but able to be changed to whatever you want. I used that into placeWalls because I was required to. I'm pretty new to java should I not have put room inside main?

Comment: *The goal is to generate an array thats 20 by 10 but able to be changed to whatever you want.* You can't change the size of an array. If you want it to be dynamically sized, you can't hardcode it to 20x10. In any case, `room[20][10]` doesn't initialize a 20x10 array; `new char[20][10]` does.

Comment: I put the 20x10 in there as a way to test the output. It's not important what size it is i wanted to be able to change it if desired

Answer (score 0):

`room` is a `char[][]`, which means that `room[20][10]`is a `char`, not a `char[][]`. You should be passing `room` itself.